# There hasn’t been a test in which he didn’t/hasn’t

Tags: grammar, present-perfect

Can anyone tell me which sentence is correct, and if they are both correct, what is the difference between them?

1. There hasn’t been a test in which he didn’t cheat.
2. There hasn’t been a test in which he hasn’t cheated.

Also, it can’t be “had cheated” because ,among other reasons, there is no other past action, can it?

Thank you!

Comment: I think the second is correct. There hasn't been a test in which he hasn't cheated, which means he has cheated in every test up to now.